# Change color of label in material-ui

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am trying change color of the subheader component. It only changes if i write like this

```
<subheader style={color.disabled} >Middle Name : </subheader>
```

where

```
const color = {
   disabled: {
    color: grey500,
  },
};
```

I am trying to change the subheader color when changing state. How can i do that?

Comment: Your approach seems to be correct. The only confusing aspect is that the color you have mentioned is the same as the default one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless I'm misunderstanding the question, there doesn't seem to be any more to this than standard use of state:

```
changeSubheader() {
  this.setState(
    subheaderDisabledColor: {
      disabled: {
        color: red500,
      },
    };
  );
};

<subheader style={this.state.subheaderDisabledColor}>Middle Name : </subheader>
```

https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#using-state-correctly